# Class Return Type Overloading

Tags: c++, design-patterns, data-structures, overloading

I commonly run into the following situation where I have a data structure which **I'd like to have** access as follows:

```
class data {
public:
    double error;
    double value;

    ...
}

...

data *outputs;

...

double lastValue = ...;
double someValue = ...;

for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    outputs[i] = someValue; //should be equivalent to outputs[i].value = someValue
    outputs[i].error = lastValue - someValue;
}
```

Currently I just use `outputs[i].value =` but, for readability purposes, it actually would make more sense to use (something similar to) the above example (at least from a theory point of view, the code doesn't require maintainability).

I understand that operator= would work for the above situation, but what about a simple access, I'd still have to use outputs[i].value. What would be the best solution to this for readability for both the conceptual design and also without causing headaches for the programmer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add an assignment operator overload to `data`:

```
class data {
public:
    double error, value;

    void operator=(double d) { value = d; }
};
```

Though, to be honest, I think this would be rather confusing.  It depends on how you intend to use it, of course, but given your example, I think it would be cleaner to add a constructor for the class:

```
class data {
public:
    double error, value;
    data(double value_arg, double error_arg)
        : value(value_arg), error(error_arg) { }
};
```

used as:

```
outputs[i] = data(someValue, lastValue - someValue);
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll probably end up using a constructor solution, it definitely seems like the cleanest and most clear for both parties.